# Jboss remoting with ssl enabled

Tags: ssl, https, jboss, remoting

i need to add Jboss remoting with ssl enable ie ,(with https). i have all the libs which required for jboss remoting.

so that i found a tutorial with server side code as follows

I want to know where do I configure "https"  and ssl .

```
import org.jboss.remoting.InvokerLocator;
import org.jboss.remoting.transport.*;

public class Server {
  public Server() throws Exception {
   InvokerLocator myLocator = new InvokerLocator("http://127.0.0.1:8888");
  Connector connector = new Connector();
  connector.setInvokerLocator(myLocator.getLocatorURI());
  connector.start();
   connector.addInvocationHandler("MYSYS",new MyInvocationHandler());
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Server();
  }
 }
```